# Subsampling time series to a certain resolution

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

To analyse the GPS-track of certain birds I want to subsample GPS-tracks to a fixed resolution of approximately 10 minutes. The actual resolution varies from 1-10 minutes (often 5 minutes as seen in snip).

```
    Tracking_data$Collecting.time

1             2022-08-23T00:04:00Z
2             2022-08-23T00:09:01Z
3             2022-08-23T00:14:01Z
4             2022-08-23T00:19:00Z
5             2022-08-23T00:24:01Z
6             2022-08-23T00:29:01Z
7             2022-08-23T00:34:00Z
8             2022-08-23T00:39:01Z
9             2022-08-23T00:44:00Z
10            2022-08-23T00:49:00Z
11            2022-08-23T00:54:01Z
12            2022-08-23T00:59:00Z
13            2022-08-23T01:04:01Z
14            2022-08-23T01:09:00Z
15            2022-08-23T01:14:01Z
16            2022-08-23T01:19:00Z
17            2022-08-23T01:24:01Z
18            2022-08-23T01:29:00Z
19            2022-08-23T01:34:00Z
20            2022-08-23T01:39:01Z
```

How can subsample to a resolution of approximately 10 minutes? As the resolution varies every now and then I can't just extract every n'th value. I tried the "zoo" package, but could not get it to work.

EDIT: Added some more info and reproducible data

This is how a snip of the df looks like, I would like to subset to positions from the closest recording to each ten minutes, so without interpolating locations.

```
             timestamp      lon      lat
1   2022-09-27 07:48:38 2.784690 51.10052
2   2022-09-27 07:59:18 2.781762 51.09489
3   2022-09-27 07:59:40 2.781980 51.09510
4   2022-09-27 08:00:30 2.782051 51.09506
5   2022-09-27 08:00:39 2.782111 51.09505
6   2022-09-27 08:08:39 2.782197 51.09488
7   2022-09-27 08:18:39 2.782242 51.09498
8   2022-09-27 08:38:38 2.782405 51.09460
9   2022-09-27 08:48:38 2.782327 51.09466
10  2022-09-27 09:08:40 2.782203 51.09470
11  2022-09-27 09:18:40 2.782353 51.09467
12  2022-09-27 09:38:39 2.782201 51.09468
13  2022-09-27 10:18:37 2.786586 51.09139
14  2022-09-27 10:48:36 2.786597 51.09133
15  2022-09-27 11:08:37 2.786529 51.09139
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want - can you provide a reproducible sample?

What's the data in the other columns, and what do you want to do with it?  If it's GPS position data, do you want to use the position from the closest recording to each ten minute "tick", or do you want to estimate the likely position at the tick by extrapolating from the existing points?

As a start, you can use dplyr to group the data:

```
df %>% group_by(group10min = cut(Collecting.time, "10 min"))
```

edit: I left out some data preparation:

Using your exact format above (including the "T" and "Z") needed to be turned into POSIX time and date format - your real example may not need this.

```
df$Collecting.time %<>% str_replace_all("T"," ") %>% str_replace_all("Z","") %>% as.POSIXct()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I added a reprodicible sample and some extra info.

Comment: When I have some time I will try to come back and fill in more, but the general approach I would recommend trying:  Take the first (earliest) timestamp as a beginning point and the last as an end point.  Create a vector of time from earliest to last in steps of 10 minutes and make that the first column of a new dataframe.  Use `mutate()` to make a second column, looking up the `lon` of the closest timestamp in your original frame, repeat for `len`.